# PaaS providers where servers don't sleep because of idleness as Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, paas, idle-processing

I am looking for a NodeJS deployment platform.

Currently I have the server deployed on Heroku wherein if your server doesn't get a hit in 30 mins, it goes to sleep. Then when the app pings the server in the form of API call the server takes time 10-20 seconds to get back which is gighly undesirable.

***Solutions read elsewhere :***

Write a small JS script to continuously ping your server in every 20 mins. But that won't work now because Heroku from 2015 has imposed a criteria that free servers will be awake only for 18 hours in a day.

Also the least tier which allows 24 hours up time is costing 7 dollars per month which I cannot afford due to high dollar conversion in my native currency.

Hence looking for a PaaS for NodeJS that allows 24 hour up time in a day for FREE even for a constrained period of time.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.openshift.com ?

Comment: No I am not aware of it.

Comment: Questions asking us to find or recommend an off-site resource are off-topic on Stack Overflow. You can read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic].